# Chrome extension error 'invalid invocation'

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, error-handling, google-chrome-devtools

Every time I try to run my extension, the window opens but none of the scripts run. I checked the extensions console and it says 'TypeError: Invalid Invocation' on background.js:2:45. I'm not really sure why changing the rules is messing things up.

Background.js looks like this:

```
chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
        actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()]
    }]);
});
```

Here's my manifest.json in case it is needed:

```
{
  "name": "Link Swapper",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Swap broken links for working ones.",
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "declarativeContent", "scripting"],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [{
    "all_frames": true,
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["content.js"]
  }],
  "icons": {
    "16": "img/icon16.png",
    "32": "img/icon32.png",
    "48": "img/icon48.png"
  },
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

It worked previously, but when I changed some of the content script logic something broke and I'm not sure what. Does anybody know why this is not working?

Comment: Your rule is lacking `conditions`.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it for me. I really have no clue what I'm doing as I didn't find the docs very helpful